# Even and odd functions and whether even/odd characteristics change with powers

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

I watched a video where a problem involved recognizing that $\sin x$ is an odd function and $\sin^3 x$ is also odd. But the presenter didn't explain why  $\sin^3 x$ is also odd. Why does the fact that the function is odd not change when it is cubed? Is there a rule where for every even power the odd function is even and for every odd power the odd function remains odd? What about for even functions?

Comment: If $f$ is odd and $g = f^3$, then $g(-x) = f(-x)^3 = (-f(x))^3 = (-1)^3f(x)^3 = -f(x)^3 = -g(x)$. You can play that game now with all variants.

Comment: @amsmath Why are you allowed to put the the negative sign from inside the parentheses to outside?

Comment: Because $(ab)^n = a^n\cdot b^n$.

Comment: 532874, that's the definition of odd function, no?

Comment: @user532874 A function $f$ is odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @amsmath Actually I still don't get $f(-x)^3=(-f(x))^3$. You are trying to prove that $g(-x)=-g(x)$ so you can't assume in the proof of $g(-x)=-g(x)$ that $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Comment: @user532874 This is trivial. You have $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Now cube.

Comment: @amsmath I'm getting confused with the notation. Let's work with the real function. How do I transform $\sin^3 (-x)$ into  $-sin^3 (x)$?

Comment: Is it so hard to replace $f$ by $\sin$?

Comment: @amsmath Oops I read $f(-x)^3=(-f(x))^3$ as $f(-x)^3=-f(x)^3$. $-f(x)^3$ is just $-g(x)$. So, I thought you were trying to prove $g(-x)=-g(x)$ by simply renaming the equation as $f(-x)^3=-f(x)^3$ which isn't a proof.

Comment: @user532874 No prob.

Comment: @amsmath One more question. When you say $f^3$ I can't grasp the actual meaning of that. $f$ is a conceptual machine whose inputs are $x$ and whose outputs are $f(x)$. Thus, you can't cube a machine but you can cube its outputs.

Comment: @user532874 You're right. However, it is a convention to write $f^3$ for the machine that first outputs $f(x)$ and then cubes this value.

Comment: @amsmath I feel that what actually constitutes a function is the most worst taught thing in school for math. I only realized a function is $f$ and not $f(x)$ 6 months ago and im a college freshman. Every problem always says "Let $f(x)$ be the function" but its not the function though. So messed up.

Comment: @user532874 I had the same problem in school. I always wondered what this mysterious $f(x)$ was that I couldn't understand. You're right -- the function is $f$, not $f(x)$. If you have some $x$, then $f(x)$ is the output value. I think it is didactically very bad what they do in school.

Comment: @amsmath agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$(-1)^{2k}=(+1)$$ and  $$(-1)^{2k+1}=(-1)$$
$$(+1)^k = (+1)$$

Thus if a function is odd we have $$f^{2k}(-x) = (-1)^{2k}f^{2k}(x)=f^{2k}(x)$$ and $$f^{2k+1}(-x) = (-1)^{2k+1}f ^{2k+1}(x)=-f^{2k+1}(x)$$

Thus odd functions to the odd powers are odd and to the even powers are even.

Even functions to any power stay even.

Comment: I think you are missing a $2k$ exponent after "Thus if a function is odd we have"

Comment: @user532874 is it fixed now?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Check your calculations. You are missing minuses.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks for informative comment. I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only the cubing, it works for anyother odd function, it is always true that the composite of odd functions is an odd function.

In your case, $f(x)=\sin x$ is an odd function and $g(x)=x^3$ is also an odd function so $g\circ f(x)= g(f(x))=g(\sin x)=\sin^3x$

Another example is $\sin x$ with any odd power for example $x^{12345}$, since both are odd functions then $\sin^{12345}x$ is also an odd function.

Or $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is also an odd function since it is the composite of $\sin x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$,and they are both odd functions.

Anyway you can just check if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ without worrying about compositions, $f(-x)=\sin^3(-x)=(\sin (-x))^3=(-\sin x)^3 =-(\sin^3x)=-f(x)$